# MySql connection with Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following code in Web.config:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <!--<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />-->
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    <providers>
      <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=LocalPC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=testDB; Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="server=localhost; database=testDB; user id=root; password=test" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

However, on this line in code:

```
readonly EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
```

I get the following error:

```
> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Entity Framework provider type
> 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6'
> registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider
> with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make
> sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is
> available to the running application. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.'
```

I have installed MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity

Can somebody please help me fix this issue?

Comment: Did you add mysql connector for Visual studio?

Comment: @AnanthCool yes it is added.

Comment: Check whether System.Data and System.Data.Entity dll is added in your project ADO.Net project folder reference list.

Comment: @AnanthCool 'System.Data' is added and 'System.Data.Entity' is not on the reference list at all. There is however 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions'.